# Python Selenium webscraper for Redfin

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to build a web scraper for redfin. I noticed that for the Redfin Estimate that the class name is called 'statsValue'. But that name exists in 5 places thus I was thinking that given that this:

[image]

class name "info-block avm" only exists one I thought I could use that to get the statsValue as it seems to be its sort of parent class.

I am totally new to webscraping and selenium. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webelement
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.redfin.com/')
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('searchInputBox')
search_box.send_keys('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach, CA 92651')
search_box.submit()

time.sleep(2)
# element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('statsValue')
# print(element[0].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('info-block avm')


driver.quit()
```

The problem I am having is when I find 'info-block avm' how do I return the value underneath it in the picture posted?

Comment: You could use an xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below examples how you can get price. Information about how to use selectors, you can find in the following links [css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

1. `price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.info-block.avm .statsValue').text`
2. `price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.avm .statsValue').text`
3. `element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('avm')`
   `price = price.find_element_by_class_name('statsValue').text`

Best practice is to use [Explicit](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) or [Implicit](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits) waits instead of `time.sleep()`.